# How to design or create View with dynamic ui controls for iOS app on the fly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, react-native-ios

Here i have to design a view based on the api response. That Api response is going to be dynamic Like it can have any ui element it can be multiple . If the is response is have UIButton properties in response need to create a button with its properties received in response.

Here from the api response I am getting multiple ui elements, these elements need to be detected at runtime and those needed to be arranged automatically in the view controller.

I have found similar solution for Android by using **json2view** it can be achieved in Android.

So is there any library or any approach by implementing this for developing iOS App.

If you have an idea or any solution let me know. Simply don't show up here for Negative marking...Have some common sense.

Comment: Do you know how many views are there in your json ? Are they limited or not ? and if you can share the json here .... SO that i can come up with my own solution

Comment: @OsamaBinBashir :- That json response is going to have dynamic uielements.. think like there is one view controller  on that view controller what ever the response is coming from api that need to apply to the design. Ex__ Registaration screen response it can have multiple UiViews, buttons, Labels, images or images views etc ....

Comment: what is the mater of negative marking. If you know the answer answer it. I don't know who marked it negative. I don't know what to call that person .....

Comment: i didnt mark it negative :D it's a good question to me i have upvoted it

Comment: @OsamaBinBashir --- Thank you. Here i got some library for archiving above approach ...https://github.com/kxzen/KXJsonUI_ios

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/4687348) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Is there any solution to this question ? A very good question for which i'm also looking for some answers...

Comment: @ Sharanya K M ...Please let me know if you got some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think navigation controls should not be dynamic. Maybe this library can help https://github.com/hyperoslo/Form